# Spatial Index/R Tree Support in Perl

Tags: perl, data-structures, spatial-index, r-tree

Anyone got any good hints for working with an RTree in Perl? Either a pure RTree implementation which is performant or something I could hijack from a GIS project? Or would it be easier to use something like SQLite's spatial index support?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [Tree::R](http://p3rl.org/Tree%3a%3aR)?

There doesn't seem to be much activity on that module, so it may not be good enough, but then again, it might be just what you're looking for.  Just play with it for a few.

Comment: I did find Tree::R and no recent activity could mean either it's as complete as the author wished it to be or it's broken. I'll give it a shot. Cheers.